# bash send file to logger line by line (cause limit 1024)

Tags: bash, logging

I have a bash script for which I send data to the syslog-ng logger. In my case, the problem is that the number of characters exceeds 1024 and are therefore truncated.
I have managed to generate a file with several lines but it continues to send the full block.

I want to send the `dhcp.leases` file to the logger and retrieve it from node-red to rework them.

`logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$(echo "$(dumpWrtPresenceDhcp)")"`

```bash
#/bin/sh
WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES="/tmp/wrtpresence_dhcp.leases"
DHCP_LEASES="/tmp/dhcp.leases"
#
dumpWrtPresenceDhcp ()
{
    echo "$(WrtPresenceDhcp)"
    sleep 1
    cat "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}"
    return
}
WrtPresenceDhcp ()
{
    # Creating a file
    touch "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}"
    touch "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}.new"
    # Prints the dhcp.leases file in 1 line separated by | in wrtpresence_dhcp.leases.new.
    cat "${DHCP_LEASES}" | awk '{print $2";"$3";"$4}' | tr '\n' '|' > "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}.new"
    # Move the wrtpresence_dhcp.leases.new file to wrtpresence_dhcp.leases.
    mv "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}.new" "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}"
    #Print 6 characters per line to get around the 1024 character limit.    
    awk '(NR % 6 == 1) {print; for(i=1; i<6 && getline ; i++) { print }; printf "\n"}' RS='|' ORS='|' "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}" > "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}.new"
    # Move the wrtpresence_dhcp.leases.new file to wrtpresence_dhcp.leases. 
    mv "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}.new" "${WRTPRESENCE_DHCP_LEASES}"
    return
}
logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$(echo "$(dumpWrtPresenceDhcp)")"
exit 0
```

My 1st test.The result was cool but I hadn't noticed that it stopped at 1024 characters.

```
Nov  5 11:15:01 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: 
ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;h
```

The code posted here, cool I have several lines but as it sends in 1 time it does not change anything in the limit.

```
Nov  5 11:17:01 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: 
ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|
ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|
ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.1
```

I want to be able to do this.

```
Nov  5 11:17:01 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|
Nov  5 11:17:01 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|
Nov  5 11:17:01 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|
Nov  5 11:17:01 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab;192.168.x.xxx;hostname|
```

I would like to send

`logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$(echo "$(dumpWrtPresenceDhcp)")" line1`

`logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$(echo "$(dumpWrtPresenceDhcp)")" line2`

`logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$(echo "$(dumpWrtPresenceDhcp)")" line3...`

Example file `/tmp/dhcp.leases` (details)

1 line equals 1 device
line [0]= milliseconds(x1000) line [1]= mac address line [2]= ip line [3]= hostname

```
0 ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab 192.168.1.12 Computer-1 *
1699250507 ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab 192.168.1.17 Computer-2 01:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab
0 ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab 192.168.1.123 TV-1 ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab
1699243309 ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab 192.168.1.13 Iphone *
0 be:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab 192.168.1.34 Android-Children be:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab
0 fd:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab 192.168.1.56 Computer-3 *
0 cd:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab 192.168.1.124 Computer-4 01:cd:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab
```

[My project](https://github.com/dckiller51/WrtPresence)

Aware of my coding limitations, I've adapted my code according to what I've read left and right. My code isn't optimum, that's for sure, but I'm learning at the same time. That's the positive side.

---

Testing the solution

`/tmp/test` (I've matched the number of characters in my actual file)

```
0 00:01:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.01 one-one-one-oneo *
0 00:02:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.02 Two-two-twoo 01:00:02:00:00:00:00
0 00:03:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.003 three-three-thr 01:00:03:00:00:00:00
0 00:04:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.04 four-four-four-fou *
0 00:05:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.005 five-five-fiv 01:00:05:00:00:00:00
0 00:06:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.006 six-six-s *
0 00:07:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.07 seven-seven-sevenn *
0 00:08:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.008 eight-eight-e *
0 00:09:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.09 nine-nine-ninenin 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:10:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.10 ten-ten-ten-t 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:11:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.011 eleven-eleven 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:12:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.12 twelve-twelve-twe 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:13:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.13 thirteen-thirte *
0 00:14:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.14 fourteen-fourteen *
0 00:15:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.015 fifteen-fifteen-fi *
0 00:16:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.4 sixteen-sixteen-sixt *
0 00:17:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.17 seventeen-seven 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:18:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.018 eighteen-eig 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:19:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.019 nineteen-ninet *
0 00:20:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.020 twenty-twenty-twe 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:21:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.021 twentyone 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:22:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.22 twentytwo-twentytwo 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:23:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.6 twentythree-twentyt 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:24:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.24 twentyfour-twentyfo 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:25:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.25 twentyfiv *
0 00:26:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.26 twentysix-twenty 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:27:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.27 twentyseven-twent 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:28:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.28 twentyeigh 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:29:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.29 twentynine-twentyn 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:30:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.30 thirty-thirty-thir 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:31:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.31 thirtyone-thirty 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
1707029378 00:32:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.32 thirtytwo-t 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:33:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.33 thirtythre 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:34:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.4 thirtyfour-t 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
```

Command:

```
</tmp/test awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=';' ORS='|\r' |
tr -d '\r' | logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport
```

Result:

```
Nov  6 12:22:58 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: 00:01:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.01;one-one-one-oneo|00:02:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.02;Two-two-twoo|00:03:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.003;three-three-thr|00:04:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.04;four-four-four-fou|00:05:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.005;five-five-fiv|00:06:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.006;six-six-s|00:07:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.07;seven-seven-sevenn|00:08:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.008;eight-eight-e|00:09:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.09;nine-nine-ninenin|00:10:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.10;ten-ten-ten-t|00:11:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.011;eleven-eleven|00:12:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.12;twelve-twelve-twe|00:13:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.13;thirteen-thirte|00:14:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.14;fourteen-fourteen|00:15:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.015;fifteen-fifteen-fi|00:16:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.4;sixteen-sixteen-sixt|00:17:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.17;seventeen-seven|00:18:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.018;eighteen-eig|00:19:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.019;nineteen-ninet|00:20:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.020;twenty-twenty-twe|00:21:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.021;
Nov  6 12:22:58 WifiAP-01 wrtdhcpleasesreport: twentytwo-twentytwo|00:23:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.6;twentythree-twentyt|00:24:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.24;twentyfour-twentyfo|00:25:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.25;twentyfiv|00:26:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.26;twentysix-twenty|00:27:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.27;twentyseven-twent|00:28:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.28;twentyeigh|00:29:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.29;twentynine-twentyn|00:30:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.30;thirty-thirty-thir|00:31:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.31;thirtyone-thirty|00:32:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.32;thirtytwo-t|00:33:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.33;thirtythre|00:34:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.4;thirtyfour-t|
```

Data missing between line 21 and line 22.
It should stop at line 20 and start again at line 21 to have a full break.

@Ed Morton
**Off topic**
To help you understand the project. I have a router and an access point running Openwrt. I want to monitor my wifi devices live under homeassistant. There are many solutions but each with varying levels of reliability. I found a script on the internet that met my expectations but it is not suitable for homeassistant. So I looked for the easiest way to do this.
The code is based on reading logs. So I found a solution to connect my Openwrt logs to homeassistant via node-red. By default in Openwrt when a device connects or disconnects it creates an entry with its mac address. Node-red reception and processing.
To have a beautiful device in homeassistant you need a name, an id. When the device connects I only know the mac address. The best solution to automate all of this and have a nice name is to look for the hostname in the dhcp.leases file. Problem when homeassistant restarts or if node-red misses some information it will consider that everyone is absent since I am already connected.The script allows you to send all devices connected to the network every 5 minutes. I take this opportunity to send the dhcp.leases information.
Now with all the information I am able in home assistant to automatically create a device with information. On which device it is connected router or access point, on which antenna, its name, its mac address, its ip address.....

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what the problem is you're trying to solve and include concise, testable sample input and expected output. You say long lines are a problem but where are they coming from and what do you want to do with them (truncate them? wrap them to the next line? something else?) Also tell us why you're doing `logger ... "$(echo "$(dumpWrtPresenceDhcp)")"` instead of just `logger ... "$(dumpWrtPresenceDhcp)"` without the added `echo`.

Comment: And please try to come up with a [mcve] that includes a minimal complete script that demonstrates just the problem you're asking for help with. We shouldn't need scroll bars to read your code, input, or output. Whatever problem you're asking for help with is currently buried among all of that code in your question thereby making it much harder for us to help you.

Comment: It looks like of the problems for the command line you provided are in `WrtPresenceDhcp ()` but I can't figure out why you're doing most of the things you're doing in that function (e.g. write to one file and then immediately move it to another, convert newlines to `|`s and then read the file again using `|`s as newlines, try to print 6 characters to avoid a 2024 character limit, etc.) so please provide sample input, expected output, and explanations for the steps in just that function so we can help you.

Comment: Agreed. Please read the section "How to turn a bad script into a good question" in the [bash info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). Good luck.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Note that ALL_UPPERCASE variable names (like `DHCP_LEASES`) are best avoided because there is a danger of clashes with the large number of special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programming.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).

Comment: I don't see how you create `/tmp/dhcp.leases` (the value of `$DHCP_LEASES`). In order to have a good set of sample inputs for testing your code, we either need to have an obscured set of data, or a command that we can run in our local enviroment that creates approximate data we can test with. Glad you're taking advice and reducing the size of your post. Now give us some sample data to work with (-; . Good luck.

Comment: I've added an example. Mine has about 30 lines (for length = 2394). This changes when a non-reference device connects to the network.

Comment: Does `awk -v dt="Nov 5 2023 18:20" -v wifiHost="WifiAP-01" -v title="wrtdhcpleasesreport" '{ print "#dbg:length($0)="length($0); printf("%s %s %s %s\n", dt, wifiHost, title, $0)}' $dhcp_leases | logger -t $wifiTag` help you? It can probably be almost this simple. Good that you posted your sample data. Not clear how you getting more thatn 1024 chars there. You may need `awk ... | **xargs** logger -t` depending if `logger` can read from std-in. You could add logic in this script to manage length of lines. Good luck

Comment: `awk -v '{ print "#dbg:length($0)="length($0); printf("%s %s %s %s\n", $0)}' /tmp/dhcp.leases | logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport`

Comment: dt, wifiHost and the title is automatic. This command works. But I'm going to flood the log file because the script runs every 5min. But thank you because it's already a great advance and reduces the code. That's why I try to put them on several lines. I was going for 6 lines of dhcp.leases per send. `(NR % 6 == 1). The addition of length 4714`

Comment: since your fields don't contain spaces: `</tmp/dhcp.leases awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=';' | fmt -960 | logger -S 1024 -t wrtdhcpleasesreport`

Comment: for `|` delimiters: `</tmp/dhcp.leases awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=';' ORS='|\r' | fmt -960 | tr -d '\r' | logger -S 1024 -t wrtdhcpleasesreport `

Comment: if your receiver supports large messages, just use `-S`: eg. `logger -S $(( $(wc -c </tmp/converted_data) + 64 )) -t wrtdhcpleasesreport -f /tmp/converted_data`

Comment: I hope you see now how all your extra explanation didn't add much to helping fix your code. (sorry (-;! ) .. A good question is 1) small set of sample data that covers any special cases and if required a "reject this record" sample 2) expected output from that sample data, 3) your (what you think should work) best attempt at code, 4) current output from your code 5) exact text of any error messages. Use proper `code/data/output/exactTxtOfErrMsgs` formatting so readers can easily copy/paste code to their environment. And read *How to turn a bad script into a good question* again (from above).

Comment: (Not criticizing!, you clearly tried to solve your problem, so kudos and keep posting!) . (And your git-hub project looks very interesting!) Good luck.

Comment: Your solution almost works. fmt: not found and -S 1024 not supported.`</tmp/dhcp.leases awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=';' ORS='|\r' | tr -d '\r' | logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport` With this command I lose 64 characters.

Comment: Try `fold` as a pedestrian replacement for `fmt`. You have not revealed which platform you're on so it's basically impossible to know which commands we can expect you to have available.

Comment: As an aside, the first two bytes in the file need to be `#` and `!` in order for the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to be valid.

Comment: ... and if the shebang says `/bin/sh` then this is a `sh` script, not a Bash script. [Difference between Bash and `sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: How about simply `while read -r line; do echo "$line" | logger; done </tmp/dhcp.leases`?

Comment: platform BusyBox v1.36.1. the while works. I can keep my commands to put 6 devices per line and then it sends them line by line. Thank you all, I think I will keep this solution even if I know it can be improved. I don't have enough knowledge for that.

Comment: @dckiller you should post an answer containing whatever the solution you're using is. I still don't understand what problem youi're trying to solve nor why you're doing some of the things you're doing (e.g. in `awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=';' ORS='|\r' |
tr -d '\r'` awk is adding a `\r` to the output and then `tr` is removing it again - why?) but maybe others with similar problems in future will benefit from it. Also, maybe if you post the solution it'll help clarify what the problem was.

Comment: We don't need any of the background information you just added at the bottom of your question, all we need is a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output and your code attempt to solve the problem you're asking about. Everything else is just irrelevant text obscuring the actual problem of you wanting to transform some text from one format to another. It makes zero difference for a solution to your problem where the input text came from or where the output text is going or why any of it is happening.

Comment: @EdMorton the `\r` was because they took my comment and removed the `fmt` from it

Comment: @jhnc ah, I see your comment now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a stab at it.

Given that you said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427114/bash-send-file-to-logger-line-by-line-cause-limit-1024/77432457#comment136501906_77427114):

> I was going for 6 lines of dhcp.leases per send

below are 3 options, pick one depending on whatever your input and desired output format are.

**Option 1:**

Given this sample input, copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143661/1745001 and then doubled in length so it contains more than 6 leases:

```
$ cat /tmp/dhcp.leases
lease 192.168.20.4 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation1";
}

lease 192.168.20.5 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
}

lease 192.168.20.6 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation2";
}


lease 192.168.20.7 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 01:00:00:00:00:00;
}

lease 192.168.20.4 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation1";
}

lease 192.168.20.5 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
}

lease 192.168.20.6 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation2";
}


lease 192.168.20.7 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 01:00:00:00:00:00;
}
```

This will call `logger` once per second with up to 6 leases at a time as it's last argument:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dhcp_leases='/tmp/dhcp.leases'

WrtPresenceDhcp() {
    awk -v maxLeases=6 -v OFS=';' '
        NF {
            gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
            lease = (linesCnt++ ? lease OFS : "") $0
        }
        $1 == "}" {
            leases = (numLeases++ ? leases "|" : "") lease
            if ( numLeases == maxLeases ) {
                print leases
                numLeases = 0
            }
            linesCnt = 0
            next
        }
        END {
            if ( numLeases ) {
                print leases
            }
        }
    ' "$dhcp_leases"
}

while IFS= read -r leases; do
    echo logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$leases"
    sleep 1
done < <(WrtPresenceDhcp)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport lease 192.168.20.4 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;;uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;;client-hostname "examle-workstation1";;}|lease 192.168.20.5 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;;}|lease 192.168.20.6 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:01;;uid 00:00:00:00:00:01;;client-hostname "examle-workstation2";;}|lease 192.168.20.7 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 01:00:00:00:00:00;;}|lease 192.168.20.4 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;;uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;;client-hostname "examle-workstation1";;}|lease 192.168.20.5 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;;}
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport lease 192.168.20.6 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:01;;uid 00:00:00:00:00:01;;client-hostname "examle-workstation2";;}|lease 192.168.20.7 {;starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;;ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;;hardware ethernet 01:00:00:00:00:00;;}
```

**Option 2**

If, on the other hand, what you show under the text

> /tmp/test (I've matched the number of characters in my actual file)

in your question:

```
$ cat /tmp/dhcp.leases
0 00:01:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.01 one-one-one-oneo *
0 00:02:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.02 Two-two-twoo 01:00:02:00:00:00:00
0 00:03:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.003 three-three-thr 01:00:03:00:00:00:00
0 00:04:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.04 four-four-four-fou *
0 00:05:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.005 five-five-fiv 01:00:05:00:00:00:00
0 00:06:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.006 six-six-s *
0 00:07:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.07 seven-seven-sevenn *
0 00:08:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.008 eight-eight-e *
0 00:09:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.09 nine-nine-ninenin 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:10:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.10 ten-ten-ten-t 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:11:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.011 eleven-eleven 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:12:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.12 twelve-twelve-twe 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:13:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.13 thirteen-thirte *
0 00:14:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.14 fourteen-fourteen *
0 00:15:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.015 fifteen-fifteen-fi *
0 00:16:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.4 sixteen-sixteen-sixt *
0 00:17:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.17 seventeen-seven 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:18:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.018 eighteen-eig 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:19:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.019 nineteen-ninet *
0 00:20:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.020 twenty-twenty-twe 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:21:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.021 twentyone 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:22:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.22 twentytwo-twentytwo 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:23:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.6 twentythree-twentyt 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:24:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.24 twentyfour-twentyfo 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:25:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.25 twentyfiv *
0 00:26:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.26 twentysix-twenty 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:27:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.27 twentyseven-twent 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:28:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.28 twentyeigh 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:29:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.29 twentynine-twentyn 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:30:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.30 thirty-thirty-thir 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:31:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.31 thirtyone-thirty 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
1707029378 00:32:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.32 thirtytwo-t 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:33:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.33 thirtythre 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
0 00:34:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.4 thirtyfour-t 01:00:09:00:00:00:00
```

is actually your input format, then this would also call `logger` with 6 leases at a time once per second:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dhcp_leases='/tmp/dhcp.leases'

WrtPresenceDhcp() {
    awk -v maxLeases=6 -v OFS=';' '
        NF {
            lease = $2 OFS $3 OFS $4
            leases = (numLeases++ ? leases "|" : "") lease
            if ( numLeases == maxLeases ) {
                print leases
                numLeases = 0
            }
        }
        END {
            if ( numLeases ) {
                print leases
            }
        }
    ' "$dhcp_leases"
}

while IFS= read -r leases; do
    echo logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$leases"
    sleep 1
done < <(WrtPresenceDhcp)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:01:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.01;one-one-one-oneo|00:02:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.02;Two-two-twoo|00:03:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.003;three-three-thr|00:04:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.04;four-four-four-fou|00:05:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.005;five-five-fiv|00:06:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.006;six-six-s
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:07:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.07;seven-seven-sevenn|00:08:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.008;eight-eight-e|00:09:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.09;nine-nine-ninenin|00:10:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.10;ten-ten-ten-t|00:11:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.011;eleven-eleven|00:12:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.12;twelve-twelve-twe
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:13:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.13;thirteen-thirte|00:14:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.14;fourteen-fourteen|00:15:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.015;fifteen-fifteen-fi|00:16:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.4;sixteen-sixteen-sixt|00:17:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.17;seventeen-seven|00:18:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.018;eighteen-eig
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:19:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.019;nineteen-ninet|00:20:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.020;twenty-twenty-twe|00:21:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.021;twentyone|00:22:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.22;twentytwo-twentytwo|00:23:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.6;twentythree-twentyt|00:24:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.24;twentyfour-twentyfo
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:25:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.25;twentyfiv|00:26:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.26;twentysix-twenty|00:27:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.27;twentyseven-twent|00:28:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.28;twentyeigh|00:29:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.29;twentynine-twentyn|00:30:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.30;thirty-thirty-thir
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:31:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.31;thirtyone-thirty|00:32:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.32;thirtytwo-t|00:33:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.33;thirtythre|00:34:00:00:00:00;192.168.1.4;thirtyfour-t
```

**Option 3**

If your input is the same as shown for **Option 1** above but you want output similar to that shown for **Option 2** above, then this would also call `logger` with 6 leases at a time once per second:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dhcp_leases='/tmp/dhcp.leases'

WrtPresenceDhcp() {
    awk -v maxLeases=6 -v OFS=';' '
        { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[;[:space:]]+$/,"") }
        $1 == "lease"    { ip = $2 }
        $1 == "hardware" { mac = $3 }
        $1 == "client-hostname" {
            gsub(/^[^"]+"|"[^"]*$/,"")
            host = $0
        }
        $1 == "}" {
            lease = mac OFS ip OFS host
            mac = ip = host = ""
            leases = (numLeases++ ? leases "|" : "") lease
            if ( numLeases == maxLeases ) {
                print leases
                numLeases = 0
            }
            next
        }
        END {
            if ( numLeases ) {
                print leases
            }
        }
    ' "$dhcp_leases"
}

while IFS= read -r leases; do
    echo logger -t "wrtdhcpleasesreport" "$leases"
    sleep 1
done < <(WrtPresenceDhcp)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:00:00:00:00:00;192.168.20.4;examle-workstation1|00:00:00:00:00:00;192.168.20.5;|00:00:00:00:00:01;192.168.20.6;examle-workstation2|01:00:00:00:00:00;192.168.20.7;|00:00:00:00:00:00;192.168.20.4;examle-workstation1|00:00:00:00:00:00;192.168.20.5;
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport 00:00:00:00:00:01;192.168.20.6;examle-workstation2|01:00:00:00:00:00;192.168.20.7;
```

For all options above, in the awk output I separated leases with `|`s and fields within a lease with `;`s as that looks like it might be you want from some of the text blocks in your question. Obviously just remove `echo` to actually call `logger`.

If what you're trying to do is something other than one of the above, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I'll test when I get home. Option 2 is the most suitable. But the loop must stop at the end of x lines of the file. Afterwards the others are interesting because you show me that there are other dhcp.leases. My goal remains to share with the homeassistant community and must remain easily adaptable for everyone.

Comment: I don't know what "the homeassistant community" means or inwhat your goal of sharing with them has to do with a solution but as I mentioned, if neither of those options in my answer do what you want then please edit your question to state what it is you want. And please try to simplify and clarify it by stating "here is the sample input" and then show that, and then say "here is the expected output" and then show that. As you can hopefully see in my answer it won't be hard to do whatever it is you want to do but first you've got to be able to tell us clearly and simply what that is.

Comment: Regarding `But the loop must stop at the end of x lines of the file.` - OK, that'll also be trivial but I don't believe you've mentioned anything about that before and you'll have to tell us in your question how to identify which line to stop at (line number? blank line? some string on that line? something else?).

Comment: Regarding `must remain easily adaptable for everyone` - that's something else you haven't mentioned before and would need to update your question to state what that means (you want others to be able to edit your code? have a config file? provide arguments? something else?, does it even really matter to the problem you're asking for help with or is it just more irrelevant text?).

Comment: must remain easily adaptable for everyone =  The final project. But the loop must stop at the end of x lines of the file = I think I'm misleading you. I will test before commenting. I meant, the loop must not go around in circles endlessly. Homeassistant  = 
Free home automation software.

Comment: The loop ends when the input ends.

Answer (score 1):

You have added my comment code to your question but left out the `fmt`, as you say you don't have it. However this breaks the code - `fmt` is the part the does the splitting into shorter lines:

```
</tmp/dhcp.leases awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=';' ORS='|\r' |
fmt -960 |
tr -d '\r' |
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport
```

There are many alternatives that approximate the behaviour of `fmt`.

For example, with just `awk`:

```
</tmp/dhcp.leases awk '
    { $0 = $2";"$3";"$4"|" }
    (t+=length)>960 { print "\n"; t=length }
    { print }
    END { print "\n" }
' ORS='' |
logger -t wrtdhcpleasesreport
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `fmt` as I usually use [fold](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fold.html) to split long lines and `fold` may be available if anyone doesn't have `fmt` since it's a POSIX defined tool. I'm not entirely sure what the expected behavior for that pipe to `fmt` is when lines are longer, short, and/or contain spaces though so idk what the `fold` equivalent, if any, would be.

Comment: @EdMorton I started on SunOS4 which was BSDish. Have somehow never encountered `fold`. Looks like `ORS='| '` and `fold -s -b960 | tr -d ' '` could work here.

Comment: I believe `fmt` splits on any whitespace. I just used `\r` as a character that probably won't exist in the data and so can be safely deleted

Comment: Looks like there's a difference in behavior for lines that are longer than the specified width - `fold` will cut them off at the specified width while `fmt` will wait til a whitespace occurs. I just tried `printf '12345 12345\n' | fold -s -w4` vs `printf '12345 12345\n' | fmt -w4`. The former output `1234
5
1234
5` while the latter `12345
12345` (all spaces newlines in both).

Comment: @EdMorton since 6 fit, I'm assuming a single data-set does too

Comment: There's a very unlikely rainy day case in the awk script - if the first record is longer than 960 chars it'll print a blank line. Maybe the test for length should come after the `print` rather than before it (but then your `END` would need to test if "\n" was alredy just printed).

Comment: @EdMorton worth noting, but if that could happen, the entire premise of writing the code needs rethinking, as overlong output to logger would result

Comment: @EdMorton btw, I test length before print otherwise **every** line emitted could end up too long. blank at start can be avoided by checking `NR>1` but I don't think that's necessary here.

Comment: @jhnc I tested the first solution with fmt. -ash: fmt: not found. I conclude that my system does not have this option. `platform BusyBox v1.36.1`. For the second I have an error. 
awk: cmd. line:3: Unexpected token.

Comment: change `length` to `length()`. apparently busybox doesn't comply with the standard which says [the parentheses are optional](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13) and it misparses the `+=`

Comment: @jhnc Works very well by adding the ()